# how to add drop down like buttons in qna maker

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-web-app-service, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

grouping of policies like admin:

[image: grouping of policies like admin]

policies under admin grouping:

[image: policies under admin grouping]

Referring to the images, I have set of grouping of policies like admin,corporate etc. when i select the admin grouping it shows up 6 other policies under it like access card policy,car parking policy etc mentioned in screenshots.

Now without clicking admin grouping, on having the mouse over it I should be able to view all the policies under admin grouping.

How it can be achieved in QnAmaker knowledge base.

Comment: Where are those images?

Comment: i have updated it in the question

Comment: You say "in QnAmaker knowledge base", as if that's the interface in which customers will be interacting with your bot. However that is a misconception. The Test panel in the qnamaker.ai portal is just a test panel. It's not an actual *channel* that customers chat with. If you see the left-hand side of [this article in MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) you can see various channels. Choose one, and figure out what rendering features it has available